# How to have connectors in PowerPoint that do not touch the shapes?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-powerpoint-2011

I have a connector between two shapes. The connector touches both shapes, i.e. there is no space or margin between the connector end and the shape.

How can I have such a margin while keeping the connection between the line and the shapes ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this directly, but you can fake it.

Add the shape, then duplicate it and then make the duplicate slightly larger than the original, centered on the original (hold CTRL and drag one of the corners).

Give the duplicate no line/no fill and group it with the original shape.

Connectors will now snap to the connection points of either the duplicate or original shape.  Snap to the dupe and you've got your margin.